# Azure DevOps compile time variables

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I know that in Azure DevOps, variables accessed like $(varname) are runtime only. But I'm struggling to understand why my code below doesn't work when I am accessing it using the compile time syntax

This is a shortened down version on my pipeline. Basically, I have the main pipeline file, then each environment (dev, etc) will have it's own .yml. This is just for organizational purposes. Each environment file will call a set of stages

**azure-pipeline.yml**

```
variables:
  - name: myVar
    value: 'one'

stages:
  # Deploy Dev
  - template: ./azure-pipeline-dev.yml
```

**azure-pipeline-dev.yml**

```
stages:
  - template: ./deploy.yml
    parameters: 
      myParam: ${{ variables.myVar }}
```

**deploy.yml**

```
parameters:
  - name: myParam
    type: string
    values:
      - one
      - two
```

When I do this I get an error saying:

/azure-pipeline-dev.yml The 'myParam' parameter value '' is not a valid value.

But my question is, since I am using the compile time syntax, why is the value not being loaded into the ${{ variables.myVar }}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am able to reproduce your issue:

[image]

The issue comes from you didn't have the step to pass variables.

> But my question is, since I am using the compile time syntax, why is
> the value not being loaded into the ${{ variables.myVar }}

template need parameter section to pass values, and only this way can pass values to template.

By the way, your definition has other problems. First, you didn't have stages structure in deploy.yml. Second, variables always string, compile time can't give the deploy.yml array via variables. Only parameters can achieve this.

***azure-pipelines.yml***

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
  - name: myVar
    value: one


stages:
  # Deploy Dev
  - template: ./azure-pipeline-dev.yml
    parameters: 
      myVar: ${{ variables.myVar }}
```

***azure-pipeline-dev.yml***

```
parameters:
  - name: myVar
    type: string
    default: 'xxx'

stages:
  - template: ./deploy.yml
    parameters: 
      myParam: ${{ parameters.myVar }}
```

***deploy.yml***

```
parameters:
  - name: myParam
    type: string
    default: xxx
    # values:
    #   - one
    #   - two
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: echo ${{parameters.myParam}}
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

This will fine on my side:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification. I was thinking I needed to pass the var in as a parameter but was hoping I could just use the global variable syntax as it would look a lot tidier. Apologies about the formatting, I was copying and redacting my var names, etc

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but in case it's helpful to anyone, you can absolutely use the global variable in the templates, you just have to reference it as a variable instead of a parameter.  That is, you could freely refer to $(myVar) in either azure-pipeline-dev.yml or deploy.yml

This works fine:

**azure-pipeline.yml**

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
  - name: myVar
    value: one

stages:
  # Deploy Dev
  - template: ./azure-pipeline-dev.yml
```

**azure-pipeline-dev.yml**

```
stages:
  - template: ./deploy.yml
    parameters:
      myParam: $(myVar)
```

**deploy.yml**

```
parameters:
  - name: myParam
    type: string
  
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: echo ${{parameters.myParam}}
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```

or just this:

**azure-pipeline.yml**

```
trigger:
- none

variables:
  - name: myVar
    value: one

stages:
  # Deploy Dev
  - template: ./azure-pipeline-dev.yml
```

**azure-pipeline-dev.yml**

```
stages:
  - template: ./deploy.yml
```

deploy.yml

```
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
    - script: echo $(myVar)
      displayName: 'Run a one-line script'
```